# Is it a good idea to use std::vector<std::any> as a parameter in a polymorphic class?

Tags: c++, c++17, polymorphism

I'm stuck in this situation.

In C++, it seems like a member function cannot be a function template (**Revise: A member function can be a function template; A virtual function cannot be a function template**!).

And that's why I cannot write an abstract method which has a variadic template.

The invalid example is shown as bellow:

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {};

    // Revise: I should not take init as an example. So I added foo as below.  
    
    // Invalid!
    template<typename... Ts>
    virtual void foo(Ts... args) = 0;  

}
```

However, I have to write an abstract method so that if I get a `Base` pointer (or ref), when I'm calling virtual function `foo()`, the implementation of a derived class would be actually called.

Under this situation, `std::vector<std::any>` comes to my mind.

For example:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {};

    // Revise: I should not take function `init()` as an example. So I changed it to function `foo()` as below.
    
    // Valid!
    virtual void foo(const std::vector<std::any>& args) = 0;
}

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    // Override {foo()} in <Base>
    virtual void foo(const std::vector<std::any>& args) override
    {
        // ......
    }
}
```

This does work, but I don't know whether it is a good idea. Would it make my program very slow? Or is there any other way to achieve **polymorpism** as well as **variadic parameters**?

Comment: Generally, `init`-type methods are an antipattern, the constructor is supposed to initialize the object. So the whole thing seems suspect to start with.

Comment: One of the advantages of OO is you can ensure a class is fully initialized when constructed. It feels like having an `init` function separate from the contructor misses this advantage. Have you thought about using some kind of factory pattern instead, where maybe you have another class that is responsible for creating objects derived from `Base`. The factory class can itself be polymorphic in some way (compile-time or run-time, as you choose).

Comment: "a member function cannot be a function template“ --- incorrect. A virtual function cannot be a template, but a virtual `init` function is a no-no. What are you trying to achieve with it? If you don't know the exact type, you don't know how to initialise the object. If you know the exact type, why are you calling a virtual function? The whole design smells wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I do should not take `init()` as an example (what I actually tried is not make `init` as a variadic template as well). I actually want **some tool function** to be a abstract function and has a variadic parameter list.

Comment: You'll probably find it very hard to do anything useful with `std::initializer_list<std::any>`. With variadic arguments you at least know the types of the arguments and can do lots of clever compile time stuff with that information.

Comment: If I know the arguments, I surly can write a template to do some compile-time stuff. However, I'm writting something like an Interface, I guess the arguments of function `foo()` should be deduced in runtime.

Comment: Having a set of derived classes, that can *all* take any number of parameters of any type, sounds overwhelmingly generic. Perhaps you should tell us *what* you want to do instead of how you tried to do it. Now this smells a bit like an [XY-problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Taking a json document or similar might be better than `std::any`... That allow also to have mostly anything... There are json schemas though to validate argument.

Comment: The general problem with `std::any` is that it is hard to work with — because you have to rummage the any instance for its data — and it's circumvents the strong typing of the language which is there to help you from shooting yourself in the foot.  The language already provides enough rope to shoot yourself in the foot.  No need to load a `std::any` round in the chamber.

Comment: `foo` is a method taking any number of parameters of any type, with no checking done at compile time.  Are you sure you want to be working in C++?  There are untyped languages out there.

Comment: `std::vector<std::any> args` is passed by copy, and the copy is likely to be expensive since `std::any` certainly performs an indirection in memory and a dynamic allocation. Can't you use at least a reference here?

Comment: @JérômeRichard Thank you for your response. I do should use `const std::vector<std::any>&` instead of  `std::vector<std::any>`. I will change that. However, I'm more wondering about whether it's a good design pattern, or whether there is a better way to both achieve **polymorpism** as well as **variadic parameters**.

Comment: IMHO, if you have `std::any` in your code, then you certainly have an issue in the way you have designed your application (it is OK for a prototype). It is not much about performance, but type safety in general. As mentioned by others, It is hard to help you with the provided information and I also agree with others that it looks like a XY problem. Regarding performance, polymorphism has an overhead and I do not expect `std::any` to be much more expensive. Both are bad for performance. I might not be a problem though : is this part of the code critical?